# Why don't exceptions work with gcc7 and -static-libgcc on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

If I compile this simple program with gcc-7, `-static-libstdc++`, and `-static-libgcc`; then run on OSX

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main() try {
  throw std::runtime_error{"abc123"};
  return 0;
} catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
  std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

it fails with error code 134.

Why doesn't it print "abc123" as it does when compiled with the same options on linux?

Comment: What is Error Code 134?

Comment: It's the return code from `$?`. It indicates [Program Abort](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs136/seashell/docs/seashell-error-codes.html#%28part._.Error_code_134_-_.Program_.Abort%29)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using this with gcc7 on OSX? It works as expected on the version of clang I have on my Mac.

Comment: @JohnPerry, yes, I'm using specific features of GCC that aren't available with clang.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed(-ish) in GCC8; see update to [PR86215](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86215) and the related [PR80556](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80556).